# Applying CSS rule to multiple pages

Tags: css

Hoping someone can help please. I have a bunch pages with similar slugs that I want to apply css rules to, i.e.

- camera-crews-uk
- camera-crews-mexico
- camera-crews-ukraine

etc etc.

How do I apply a css rule to all pages with 'camera-crews' in the slug please?

Many thanks,
Spencer

Comment: Are you using wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

CSS has no mechanism for applying rules based on the URL of the page.

You'll need to use a programming language to change the DOM of the page so that it either:

- Dynamically includes the CSS
- Dynamically includes something (e.g. a class) which a CSS selector can match

Comment: That's true in a sense, but it he is using wordpress then this is possible by using the category classes that are included in the body

Comment: @fraggley — That is the second of the solutions I offered in this answer

Comment: You did indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an external stylesheet and connect the HTML pages that you want to apply the styles on connected to that stylesheet.